# Binding multiple objects into JSP form:form tag

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have a JSP *singup-form.jsp* which includes basically 2 kinds of information:

1. user infos
2. account infos

*singup-form.jsp* :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Sign up</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    <form:form action="processSignup" method="GET" modelAttribute="user">
        <p>*First name</p>
        <form:input path="firstName"/>

        <p>Middle name</p>
        <form:input path="middleName"/>

        <p>*Last name</p>
        <form:input path="lastName"/>

        <form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="account">
            <p>*Email</p>
            <form:input path="userName"/>

            <p>*Password</p>
            <form:password path="password"/>
        </form:form>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />

    </form:form>    
</body>
</html>
```

When *signup-form.jsp* is loaded, I create 2 separate models in my *SignupController.java* through `openSignupForm(Model userModel, Model accountModel)` method:

```
package tech.devhq.account.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import tech.devhq.account.model.Account;
import tech.devhq.account.model.User;

@Controller
@Scope("singleton")
public class SignupController {

    @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public String openSignupForm(Model userModel, Model accountModel) {
        User user = new User();
        userModel.addAttribute("user", user);

        Account account = new Account();
        accountModel.addAttribute("account", account);

        return "signup-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processSignup")
    public String processSignupForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @ModelAttribute("account") Account account) {
        return "welcome";
    }   
}
```

When form is getting submitted, I want to pass both models to the *welcome.jsp* page in order to print out corresponding field names. The method `processSignupForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @ModelAttribute("account") Account account)` of the controller class above should do this.

Requirement here is that fields of *signup-form.jsp* should be handled separately with *User* and *Account* models.

**RESULT** is as following:

1. There is no compilation error
2. There is no runtime error
3. */signup-form* URL is getting opened - no problem here as well
4. I fill out the form which consist of user (first name, middle name and last name) and account information (email/username and password) and submit the button
5. No action, no page load, no error, no changes happening..previous page - signup-form is remaining as it was before

Some checked **WORKAROUNDS** which did **NOT** resolve:

1. I tried to have one single model in controller and encapsulate both *User* and *Account* objects into it
2. I tried to have just one single form with 5 mentioned fields above, but 2 *modelAttribute* element in the form. Like: *modelAttribute="user"* *modelAttribute="account"*
3. Also I have tried to have a form consisting of the sub forms, one for *User* and once for *Account* respectively. In this way I was trying to process the parent form with the hope that 2 child forms will automagically find their model to be bound, because I had 2 models for them
4. Of course I have tried to benefit answers around similar questions in StackOverflow. None of them helped

**I would like to have a solution with the minimum amount of code change, if this would be an easy win.**

EDIT: hope this edit will help to narrow the source of problem so that excluding the following portion from *signup-form.jsp* which is related to *Account* information, **WORKS** fine, **BUT** of course I do not get any information about account, but only about user on the *welcome.jsp* page:

```
<%-- 
<form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="account">
        <p class="field-name">*Email</p>
        <form:input path="userName"/>

        <p class="field-name">*Password</p>
        <form:password path="password"/>
    </form:form> 
--%>
```

Thanks for tips and brainstorming!

Bests,
Seymur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with your workaround attempts, but maybe missed some detail that tied it all together. You do need just one `<form:form>` and one model with both sets of fields in it, either with sub-objects or directly.

But if you use sub-objects, you need to name your JSP fields like `user.firstName`.

e.g.

```
public class MyModel {
    private User user;
    private Account account;
    ... getters & setters
}
```

and

```
<form:form ... modelAttribute="myModelBean">
    ...
    <form:input path="user.firstName"/>
    ...
    <form:input path="account.userName"/>
    ...
</form:form>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!

Ok, I followed the approach you suggested above. Now:

I have a SignupModel.java class. This aggregates User and Account classes, have all getters and setters for the fields of the User and Account classes.

I have adjusted signup-form.jsp accordingly. So now there is just one form:form with the single model reference: .. modelAttribute="signupModel"

Comment: Result after change:
- no compilation error, but there is runtime error "Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [tech.devhq.account.model.SignupModel]: Getter for property 'firstName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: I guess if I would copy-paste EVERYTHING from User and Account class and put all these together into SignupModel, result should be "fine". But this would sound even more dirtier way.

Is there any other way than having same getters and setters of User and Account again in SignupModel class?

Comment: So `SignupModel` has a `public User getUser() {}` method, and your JSP uses `<input path="user.firstName">`? That should be all it takes. That error looks like you're still trying to get `firstName` directly from the top level of `SignupModel`

Comment: Apparently my guess above is true, because when I add e.g. firstName attribute into the recently created class - SignupModel, I get first issue resolved and now runtime error occurs with the middleName with the same message..So I should have all fields in SignupModel which is not a nice solution

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do that. As long as your JSP references `user.firstName`, not just `firstName`, Spring can manage the field inside the sub-object. We do this all the time with our Spring MVC apps. Even more than two levels deep

Comment: cool! code got quite optimized and it works at least partially:
`@Component
public class SignupModel {
 
 @Autowired
 private User user;
 
 @Autowired
 private Account account;
 
 public User getUser() {
  return user;
 }
 
 public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user=user; 
 }
 
 public Account getAccount() {
  return account;
 }
 
 public void setAccount(Account account) {
  this.account=account;
 }
}`

The only thing is not being retrieved from `signupModel` is account information

Comment: And you use `<input path="account.userName">` for those?

Comment: yes, exactly. All works as expected and perfectly now. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: what if an array of account? how to write its path in jsp?